# Apache FOP API reference

Tags: java, apache, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I've started playing around with Apache FOP 1.1 for a project that I'm working on and for the life of me, I cannot find an API reference or documentation anywhere.

Much appreciated if someone could point me to where the API reference resides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not download the sources and build your copy of the API documentation? The ant build script has a target "javadocs" to do so.

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/download.html

Comment: Thanks heaps, javadocs ant target gave me what I need. Unfortunately, don't have enough rep to vote up the answer.